# Printing large images as multiple A4 sheets using IrfanView?

Tags: printing, irfanview

I have a massive image about 980px wide and 3000+px high. I want to print this on multiple A4 sheets of paper, how can I do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Apparently [this is not supported](http://en.irfanview-forum.de/vb/showthread.php?5999-Print-large-images-over-multiple-pages) in IrfanView – there are a few standalone tools that allow for it:

- Paint, bizarrely enough:

  > [How to Easily Print a Large Image to Multiple Pages in Windows | Scottie’s Tech.Info](http://scottiestech.info/2009/08/08/how-to-easily-print-a-large-image-to-multiple-pages-in-windows/)
  >
  > - Open the image you’d like to print in Paint
  > - Select: Print -> Page Setup (Vista and 7), or File -> Page Setup (in XP)
  > - Under Scaling, select Fit to and change the setting to something like “2 by 2 page(s)”
  > - Click OK
  > - Print the image from Paint, and make sure to select “All Pages”
- [PosteRazor](http://posterazor.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Yeah, I find it a little odd that such basic functionality isn't supported on irfanview.

Comment: Hard to believe, but this still works in 2019! Even though I usually use `IrfanView` as referenced by Tomasito below, I found that in this instance `Paint` was the easiest and best option. #ProTip: To save ink, print to PDF first to see what your poster will look like. If you like the result just print it. Otherwise start over again without having wasted a ton of ink. https://www.digitalcitizen.life/print-large-image-multiple-pages-4-steps-using-microsoft-paint

Answer (score 10):

Irfan View not out of the box, but possible:

Go to: `Options->Export Image Tiles->Set Rows and Columns`. Next you can print individual images or in `Thumbnails` mode.

Comment: Yes, this works well. I just confirmed I was able to split a long infographic into 3 by exporting as "1 x 3".

Comment: UPDATE: This method still works, but for me, the `Paint` method from Journeyman Geek works better.

Comment: This should be the #1 answer.  It gives you a good ability to preview the slices.  When I tried the suggested approach with Paint, it did not display a proper preview so it was not very confidence inspiring.  Also in paint, it opens with a default resolution and the pasted image only gets a sub-part of that, so I would have likely gotten a bunch of unwanted printed whitespace.

Answer (score 4):

I use [Posterazor](http://posterazor.sourceforge.net/) all the time. For me, it works for printing large images on different sheets of paper and has features I find useful.

(Disclaimer: I am not associated with the Posterazor product in any way.)

Answer (score 1):

Check your printer driver options. Some printer/copier manufacturers include this functionality out of the box, calling it Poster mode, or some variation thereof.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution using Irfanview: I divided the picture 'by hand' in separate files, one for every sheet. I selected the part of the picture for one separate sheet, cropped it (Irfanview menu Edit --> Crop selection (Ctrl+Y) ) and saved it as a separate file. It was cumbersome, but it gave me more control and a better end result.